# does android provide options for background fill?

Tags: android, background-image

If i set small image as background for view, it is scaled to the view size. So if view will be of the screen size, image will be greatly enlarge. Is it possible to fill background placing same image side by side to itself?

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#setTileModeXY(android.graphics.Shader.TileMode, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode)

Comment: @pskink thanksm found it. You can post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use BitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY method